# Data processing and algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I'm stuck and in search of a methodical approach or an optimized solution for the following problem.

I acknowledge it is bit lengthy and wanted to convey my aim to maximize clarity.

I have an application (A) which consolidates & sends data packets (group of contact details) to 3 third-party applications (T1, T2, T3) for processing on different time schedule. All these third-parties process data in same fashion. We are equally maintaining all these three in order to avoid service dependency and delay.

‘A’ consolidates data (max up to 25 MB) between 8-10 am and sends to T1 for processing.

‘A’ consolidates data (max up to 35 MB) between 10.1-12 pm and sends to T2 for processing.

‘A’ consolidates data (max up to 15 MB) between 14-16 pm and sends to T3 for processing.

Most frequently, some of the third-parties only process a portion of supplied data from ‘A’ due to its overload or given data quality. And these third-party applications will report back to 'A' with data those are processed and those are unprocessed. Once I have unprocessed data at my end (at application ‘A’), I wanted to retry uploading this unprocessed data (data factor) to other available third-parties (excluding the third-party who rejected it first) until all data is processed or I reach every available third-party.

i.e. If T1 leave some data unprocessed from A (8-10 am slot), then I can either approach T2 or T3 or both of them if T2 or T3 factor data further. Similarly;

If T2 has unprocessed from A (10.1-12 pm slot), then I can either approach T1 or T3 or both of them if T1 or T3 factor data further.

If T3 has unprocessed from A (14-16 pm slot), then I can either approach T1 or T2 or both of them if T1 or T2 factor data further.

Finally, toward end of a specific day (18 pm), I need to save all non-processed data from all the third-party to my local database.

I have a draft version of algorithm in mind, which essentially use three queues (represent T’s as consumer) and a producer data structure (represent A). This producer data structure will push data chuck in individual queue along with an expiry time stamp. However, I am not able to lead it to a conclusion.

Thanks in advance if you could guide to have an optional solution.

Comment: So at what time does T1 report back to A what he did processed and unprocessed?

Comment: I must be missing something: Queue everything for T1. Once that returns, queue anything that's left for T2. Once that returns, queue anything that's left for T3. What you have left after T3 returns couldn't be processed.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, Thanks and in reality, we have two choices in our system. i.e real-time approach where A gets details on unprocessed data from T1 anytime after 10 am, T2 anytime 12 pm, T3 anytime after 16. And finally save all unprocessed by end of day. Other choice is offline. i.e. A shall receive unprocessed data next day from T1,T2,T3 individually and then we manually filter and save. Let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, Thanks. We can't queue everything for any particular third-party since we wanted to distribute the data those are generated overtime (in a day) and avoid dependency on any third-party.